# Robocopy Commands ad switches

Tags: robocopy

On Robocopy commands/switches
we get requests to move a huge number of files and most of them have dates that were created. Most of the files they want to remove are OLD file - from 2/xx/16
to 5/xx/2017. They have different files names. what's the easiest way to code this using robocopy.

Answer (score 2):

Robocopy has `/MINAGE` and `/MAXAGE` options. Use those to specify a date range for file selection.
See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx#Move_files_over_14_days_old:

> ## Move files over 14 days old
>
> Move files over 14 days old (note the MOVE option will fail if any
>   files are open and locked).
>
> ROBOCOPY C:\SourceFoldern D:\DestinationFolder /move /minage:14
>
> Similarly you could use the below switches
>
> ```
> /maxage: <N> Specifies the maximum file age (to exclude files older than N days or date).
> /minage: <N>  Specifies the minimum file age (exclude files newer than N days or date).
> /maxlad: <N> Specifies the maximum last access date (excludes files unused since N).
> /minlad: <N> Specifies the minimum last access date (excludes files used since N) 
> If N is less than 1900, N specifies the number of days. Otherwise, N specifies a date in the format YYYYMMDD
> ```